# WINVER, winsock and htonl()

Tags: windows, winsock

When I don't define WINVER, my (msvc9) build is peppered with warnings and it says it is defaulting to 0x0600 (Vista) but it builds OK.  When I define WINVER = 0x501 (XP), I get this error :-

```
error C3861: 'htonl': identifier not found
```

I'd rather use WINVER=0x0501 than 0x0600 but I don't know how to fix it!

I noticed something in http://west-chamber-season-2.googlecode.com/svn-history/r2/trunk/wcs2_cli.c

```
#ifdef WINVER
#include <winsock.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#endif
```

Do I need to do something odd like this? Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like htonl is in  `Winsock2.h`, have you tried to include it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling for windows then #include winsock2.h and ws2tcpip.h and link to ws2_32.lib. Also ensure you call `WSAStartup` before you try any networking functions.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but this looks interesting.
If _WIN32_WINNT is defined somewhere to equal WINVER then this would explain my problem.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h

`   #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x600)
    #ifndef _WINSOCK2API_
    #ifdef _WINSOCKAPI_
     #error MFC requires use of Winsock2.h
    #endif
     #include <winsock2.h>
    #endif`